# Removing elements that in another array

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two arrays in python. I want to remove all the elements that present in first array. Here an example of arrays:

```
array1 =[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
array2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 3, 6, 9, 4, 8, 5, 10, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

The result would be:

`array2 = []`

Here what I've done:

```
for x in array1:
    for y in array2:
        if x==y:
            array2.remove(x)

print (array2)
```

But I'm seeing [10] as result. Why? And how to fix this?

Comment: You can create sets using both the arrays and subtract one from other to get the result.

Comment: Because ```remove``` removes just first occurrence of the element. You really need to go down to ```set``` if you want to remove all duplicated elements

Comment: As you are modifying the list while iterating, the case where the elements that to be removed are consecutive, only some occurrences of the element will be removed. So, better to use list comprehension to remove the elements as described below in the answers.

Comment: Sets really shouldn't be used in the case that there are duplicates in `array2` that should be kept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`filtered_arr = [i for i in array2 if i not in array1]`

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the issue has to do with how you are looping and removing items in the list, making the program skip over the third `10`.

You can use a quick list comprehension to solve the issue:

```
array3 = [i for i in array2 if i not in array1]
```

This is basically a simpler way of typing:

```
array3 = []
for i in array2:
    if i not in array1:
        array3.append(i)
```

---

Additionally, you probably wouldn't want to use sets. For example:

```
array1 = [1, 2, 3]
array2 = [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6]

array3 = list(set(array2) - set(array1))
```

`array3` will only contain `[4, 5, 6]`, rather than `[4, 4, 5, 6]`, since `set`s cannot contain duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

```
def diff(first, second):
    return [item for item in first if item not in second]
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example of unexpected behavior when modifying a list while iterating over it:

```
a = [10, 10]
for x in a:
  if x == 10:
    a.remove(x)
    print 'item removed'
```

After the first removal, the second `10` element becomes the first element of the list and `x` has already pointed to the first element (position 0). Thus the second iteration will never occur.